# I would like to save a text into a file without parsing in PHP

Tags: heredoc

I have a variable in my code that I like to save it into a file with out any parsing. As you can see I have some `$ sing` and `\` and etc. The problem is the text is long and I do not want you use skipping characters like `\`.
I know if I use double quote PHP will parse the `$variable` and I know about heredoc which is same as double quote. Do we have any way to NOT parse anything in the text??

for example.

```
$template = "
    minimum-stability: dev
    prefer-stable: true
    repositories:
    -{$name}
    type: composer
    url: 'https://8'
    -
    type: composer
    url: 'https://packagist.org'
    scripts:
         'omphinc/extender': '^1.1'
    ...
    ...
"
```

Comment: Put the text in single quotes and escape the ones inside the text using a backslash in front of them, like: `$template = 'minimum-stability: dev [...] \'omphinc/extender\': \'^1.1\'

Comment: Thank you. but it is a long text and I do not want to use backslash. any other solutions?

Comment: If you don't want to manually add the backslashes because the text is too long you can perform a regex against the text and automatically add them. Anyway, where the text comes from? Do you manually write it down into the PHP file?